How do I filter the suggestions in flutter's SearchField Package?
List<RowData> rowsData = [
    RowData(),
  ];

final selectedValues = <String>{};
Widget buildRow(int index, setState) {
    final focus = FocusNode();
    return Column(
      children: [
        SearchField(
          focusNode: focus,
          onSuggestionTap: (value) {
            setState(() {
              // setState;
              selectedValues.add(rowsData[index].bahanController.text);
            });
            focus.unfocus();
            // setState;
          },
          validator: (value) {
            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
              return 'Please fill out this form';
            }
            return null;
          },
          controller: rowsData[index].bahanController,
          suggestions: kodeArtList.where((suggestion) => !selectedValues.contains(suggestion)).map((String value) {
            return SearchFieldListItem(
              value,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Text(value),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
          searchInputDecoration: inputDecoration('Select Material Code'),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 15,
        ),
        ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: rowsData[index].subRows.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, subIndex) =>
              buildSubRow(index, subIndex, setState),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: index != 0 ? [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (rowsData.length < kodeArtList.length) {
                  setState(() {
                    rowsData.add(RowData());
                    setState;
                  });
                } else {
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      ),
                      title: const Text('No More Existing Materials'),
                      content:
                          const Text('Add More Material Master to Proceed'),
                      actions: [
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child: const Text('Close'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
              child: const Text('Add Row'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  rowsData.removeAt(index);
                  setState;
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Remove Row'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  rowsData[index].addSubRow();
                  setState;
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Add Series'),
            ),
          ]
              :
          [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (rowsData.length < kodeArtList.length) {
                  setState(() {
                    rowsData.add(RowData());
                    setState;
                  });
                } else {
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      ),
                      title: const Text('No More Existing Materials'),
                      content:
                      const Text('Add More Material Master to Proceed'),
                      actions: [
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child: const Text('Close'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
              child: const Text('Add Row'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  rowsData[index].addSubRow();
                  setState;
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Add Series'),
            ),
          ]
          ,
        ),
        const Divider(
          thickness: 1,
          color: Colors.black54,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 15,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

The code above has a bug.  Let me try to explain this as simple as i can. buildRow() is used to dynamically add rows of SearchFields inside the widget tree. The code above filters the suggestions where it contains the same value as in the selectedValues map, but when i tried to change the selected value in the same SearchField, it doesn't remove the initial chosen value from the selectedValues map as it is not been selected yet in any other SearchFields. So for example in 1 SearchField I initially selected the value 'ABC', but then i decided to change my mind and changed the selected value to 'CBA' in the same SearchField. Now both 'ABC' and 'CBA' are removed from the suggestions list. If I kept on going in the same SearchField, changing my selected value over and over again, there would be nothing left to show in the suggestion as they are all added to the selectedValues map. Let me know if you need more clarification or information for this bug. Below is the code for RowData
class RowData {
  List<SubRowData> subRows = [SubRowData()];

  TextEditingController bahanController = TextEditingController();

  void addSubRow() {
    subRows.add(SubRowData());
  }
}

class SubRowData {
  TextEditingController seriController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController qtyRollController = TextEditingController();
}

